# Show folders in listbox and subfolders in another listbox

Tags: c#, datagridview, listbox, thumbnails, subdirectory

I'm trying to create an Autocad plugin to preview thumbnails in datagridview

I have two listboxes I want to binding them together and show the .bmp in datagridview

1. listbox1 show Directory
2. listbox2 show subfolder from the selected folder (listbox1)
3. and then the .bmp files show in datagridview

I succeed to figure the first question

```
String[] dirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(@"D:\test\Blocks");
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < dirs.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(dirs[i]));
        }

        String[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\test\Blocks");
        for (i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(Path.GetFileName(files[i]));
        }
```

Comment: I'm tried 
if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
{
listBox2.Items.Add(listBox1.SelectedItem);
}

Comment: Loop through the GetFiles of the selected folder in ListBox1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, the first listbox lists subfolders, and when one is selected, the second listbox shows the subfolders of the selected item, and when one of those is selected, the datagridview shows the files in that folder.

If that's correct, one way to do this would be, in the Form_Load event, set the datasource of your listbox1 to the root directory. Then in the SelectedIndexChanged event for that listbox, you can set the datasource of the listbox2 to be the item selected in listbox1. And in the SelectedIndexChanged event of listbox2, you can set the datasource of the DataGridView to the item selected in listbox2.

Something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string rootDirectory = @"D:\test\Blocks";

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = Directory.GetDirectories(rootDirectory)
            .Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
        listBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        listBox2.SelectedIndexChanged += ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void ListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var parentDir = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
        listBox2.DataSource = Directory.GetDirectories(parentDir)
            .Select(Path.GetFileName).ToList();
    }

    private void ListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var parentDir = Path.Combine(rootDirectory, listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), 
            listBox2.SelectedItem.ToString());
        dataGridView1.DataSource = Directory.GetFiles(parentDir)
            .Select(f => new { FileName = Path.GetFileName(f) }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks its work but there is another question :
the two listboxes show full path. I need them to show only file name

Comment: You can use `Path.GetFileName` to get the file or directory name from a path (whatever the last portion of the path is), and we can set this as the datasource. But if we do this, then we need to construct the path when we set the data source, since the whole path isn't stored in the listbox anymore. I updated the code above to do this. Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Comment: thanks a lot @Rufus L for your answer, Its work great

Comment: sorry @Rufus but datagridview display red x instant of display .bmp files

DataGridViewImageColumn dgvimgcol = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            dgvimgcol.ImageLayout = DataGridViewImageCellLayout.Stretch;
            dgvimgcol.Width = 250;
            dgvimgcol.HeaderText = "Blocks";
            dgvimgcol.Image = null;
            dataViewImages.RowTemplate.Height = 300;
            dataViewImages.Columns.Add(dgvimgcol);
            dataViewImages.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataViewImages.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;

Comment: If this was working a month ago and now it's not, I guess you have to look at what changed (either in code or on the file system) since then. If you get stuck on debugging, feel free to ask a new question!